# convertir string a int en php

Tags: php, html

necesito actualizar datos que me trae una variable de html a php con `$_REQUEST` de tipo numérico, pasa que `$_REQUEST` da string y lo necesito en int ya que necesito hacer un decremento a la base de datos.

Código html:

```
        <form class="caja2" method="post" action="ModificarTenis.php">

        <h2 class="titulo">Introduce la ID y cantidad del producto que desees comprar aquí:</h2>

        <input type="text" name="ID" placeholder="ID" class="usuario">

        <input type="text" name="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad"class="usuario">

        <input type="submit" name="entrar" value=" Comprar " class="entrar">

    </form>
```

Código php:

````
$quitar = $_REQUEST['cantidad'];  
    $id = $_REQUEST['ID'];  
    $cantidad = "Select Stock from tenis where ID = '$id'";  
    $nuevo=intval($cantidad, $quitar);  
    //En esta linea va la variable conexión que hace el mysqli_connect en lugar de este comentario  
    $registros=mysqli_query($conexion, "update tenis set Stock='$nuevo' where ID='$id") or die("No es posible comprar en este momento");  
    if($registros){  
    echo "Compra exitosa. Gracias por preferir Zapaterías Pilli";  
    }  
    else {  
    echo "No hay más stock de este producto o no existe";  
    }  ``` 
P.D: cuando se ejecuta este código, me da el die de $registros
````

Comment: ¿Has probado a quitar las comillas simples al hacer la asignación a Stock en el update? Y yo le echaría un ojo a los PDOStatement para evitar inyecciones SQL.

Comment: ¿te refieres a $_REQUEST['ID'] o a $_REQUEST?

Comment: @RubioRic efectivamente, lo intenté y sigue sin servir. No sé a qué te refieres con lo demás xD

Comment: @JeanGotopo me refiero a $_REQUEST ['cantidad'], ya que necesito decrementar mi Stock de la base de datos conforme a lo que 'cantidad' valga

Comment: @UriSamuelDuránValencia y en la base de datos, cantidad es un INT o varchar?

Comment: @JeanGotopo en la base de datos Stock es int, no tengo una llamada cantidad, pues cantidad es el $_REQUEST que me trae el html

Comment: @Te dé una respuesta, recuerda que en html puedes validar la entrada con el type de los inputs, si dejas cantidad como type text, puede que el usuario ingrese texto y lo permita

Comment: Bueno, yo investigaría un poco sobre esos dos conceptos cuando puedas :-)

Comment: sin duda que sí, @RubioRic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa type casting para tu variable del POST para convertirlo a un int

```php
$numb = "12";
var_dump($numb);

# Imprime
# string(2) "12"

# Ahora con type casting
$numb = (int)$numb;
var_dump($numb);

# Imprime
# int(12)
```

Entiendo que estas haciendo una llamada a una base de datos, pero estara fallando porque no estas conectando a la base de datos en ningun momento para devolver el stock actual. Tendras que hacer ejecutar el SQL primero para obtener stock.

```php
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "Select Stock from tenis where ID = '{$id}'");
$cantidad = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

del array devuelto en $cantidad, saca el valor que vas a usar para tu calculo

Comment: solucioné el problema gracias a esto, sin embargo ahora cuando resto $quitar a mi Stock siempre me da 0. Es decir, en mi base de datos tengo Stock como 32 y cuando le resto $quitar = 2; da 0

Comment: Que query estas usando para actualizar tu stock?

Comment: Estas usando $nuevo = $cantidad - (int)$quitar?

Comment: $cantidad es un array devuelto por tu query a la BD

Comment: mi query es: $registros=mysqli_query($conexion, "update tenis set Stock=$nuevo where ID=$id") or die("No es posible comprar en este momento");

Comment: y mis variables son: $quitar = $_REQUEST['cantidad'];
   $id = $_REQUEST['ID'];
   $cantidad = "Select Stock from tenis where ID = $id";
   $a=(int)$cantidad;
   $b=(int)$quitar;
   $nuevo=$a - $b;

Comment: Si imprimes $nuevo que te da?

Comment: me dá -2, y el dato que dí en $_REQUEST['cantidad'] fué 2, es decir que me está tomando $a como 0

Comment: Entonces $cantidad esta recibiendo 0 de tu query? que pasa cuando das var_dump a $cantidad?

Comment: string(40) "Select Stock from tenis where ID = 22134"

Comment: si se lo doy a $a da int (0)

Comment: Ya, lo que pasa es que estas poniendo el query literal (la cadena SQL), pero no lo estas ejecutando, tienes que mandar a llamar una funcion para que te haga la consulta a la DB

Comment: y qué función es, disculpa?

Comment: Te lo voy a poner ahi en la respuesta

Comment: Ahora no se puede convertir $cantidad a int puesto que es un mysqli_result, por lo tanto, no puedo restar $cantidad - $b @AugustoM

Comment: Tienes que hacer un var_dump al resultado del query, que te devuelve?

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Ok entonces ahora que tienes un objeto de mysql_result lo conviertes a un array, ahi te actualice la pregunta, haz un print_r de ese array y saca el valor que vas a usar en tu calculo

Comment: Amigo, muchísimas gracias. Ya he podido. Me has salvado toda mi preparatoria jajaja. No sé que hora es en tu país pero agradezco infinitamente tu tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

La función `intval()` convierte una cadena en una int.

El parámetro que esa función aceptan es una cadena o string y el valor de retorno es un número entero.

Creo que el error lo tienes porque en la función estás usando dos parámetros. Además, esto: `$cantidad = "Select Stock from tenis where ID = '$id'";`  No es muy entendible.

Por otra parte, si tu mismo hiciste el html, puedes hacer el input de cantidad como tipo número quedando así

```
 <input type="number" name="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad"class="usuario">
```

Comment: es que no necesito un input para $cantidad puesto que su valor necesito que sea lo que tengo en Stock de mi base de datos

Comment: @UriSamuelDuránValencia ok entiendo ahora, solo que el input con cantidad confunde un poco

Comment: vale, cierto, debería darle otro nombre. Gracias por tu ayuda en general